# How can I keep the values in a column of 2 separate rows adjacent using the boostrap grid when they collapse?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap grid that looks like this ( [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h81jka6y/) ):
[image: Wide Viewport]

When the columns collapse on a small viewport, it looks like this:
[image]

My desired output is this:

[image]

I'm not sure what the best way is to make the columns stay together since bootstrap condenses them into individual rows

Code:

```
   <div class="list-group list-group-large list-group-background list-group-background-data settings">
  <div class="list-group-header">
  <div class="list-group-title">
    <h3>Set Alerts</h3>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-large list-group-data">
            <div class="top-row row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><span>Field</span></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><span>Condition</span></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><span>Value</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><span>Units</span></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><span>Save/Delete</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="alarm in alarms">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Roll</option>
            <option>Pitch</option>
            <option>Yaw</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control">
                  <option>is greater than</option>
                  <option>is less than</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
      <span>deg</span>
      </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button"class="btn btn-success-outline">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
                </div>
      </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why would you divide the field labels and the actual input elements in different rows? This is just a bad design decision. Fix it.

Comment: There will usually be more than one row of input elements so the field labels would act as headers on wide viewports, and labels on small viewports

Comment: Repeat the labels then. Use neighboring selectors in media queries to hide them on large screens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<label></label>
```

Checkout the JSFiddle below

https://jsfiddle.net/sg05vdj8/1/